# munmap of an unlinked file - is the data flushed?

Tags: linux, macos, mmap

I am interested in using an mmap'ed file as a private swap space in case the machine doesn't have enough RAM for my huge tables. When I'm done with this processing, I no longer need these tables and hence there is no need to flush the data to disk if not already done so. Would mmap followed by unlinking the file (or alternatively opening a file with O_TMPFILE) cause munmap to skip flushing, since the file will be deleted anyway upon munmap (assuming its the only open reference to the file)? I'm primarily interested in Linux, but would also like to know the answer for MacOS.